# complete list if the first and last element is equal

Tags: python, list

I have a problem trying to transform a list.

The original list is like this:

```
[['a','b','c',''],['c','e','f'],['c','g','h']]
```

now I want to make the output like this:

```
[['a','b','c','e','f'],['a','b','c','g','h']]
```

When the blank is found ( '' ) merge the three list into two lists.

I need to write a function to do this for me.

Here is what I tried:

```
for x in mylist:

    if x[len(x) - 1] == '':

        m = x[len(x) - 2]
        for y in mylist:
            if y[0] == m:
                combine(x, y)


def combine(x, y):
    for m in y:
        if not m in x:
            x.append(m)
    return(x)
```

but its not working the way I want.

Comment: What does "not working like i want" mean? what *does* it do?

Comment: Do you mean that the `('')` is a marker to indicate that the following lists should have the first list joined on the front?

Comment: yes this is what i mean when the loop find the ( ' ' ) should bring every list with the same last element before the ( ' ' ) and its first element

Comment: So what should happen if the first list was `['a','','c']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
mylist = [['a','b','c',''],['c','e','f'],['c','g','h']]


def combine(x, y):
    for m in y:
        if not m in x:
            x.append(m)
    return(x)

result = [] 

for x in mylist:

    if x[len(x) - 1] == '':

        m = x[len(x) - 2]
        for y in mylist:
            if y[0] == m:
                result.append(combine(x[0:len(x)-2], y))

print(result)
```

your problem was with

```
combine(x[0:len(x)-2], y)
```

output :

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h']]
```

Comment: btw `x[len(x) - a]` can be rewritten as `x[-a]`. And `x[0:len(x) - a]` can be rewritten as `x[0:-a]`.

Comment: thank you u solve it for me with this  combine(x[0:len(x)-2], y)

Answer (score 0):

Your code *almost* works, except you never do anything with the result of `combine` (print it, or add it to some result list), and you do not remove the `''` element. However, for a longer list, this might be a bit slow, as it has quadratic complexity O(n²).

Instead, you can use a dictionary to map first elements to the remaining elements of the lists. Then you can use a loop or list comprehension to combine the lists with the right suffixes:

```
lst = [['a','b','c',''],['c','e','f'],['c','g','h']]

import collections
replacements = collections.defaultdict(list)
for first, *rest in lst:
    replacements[first].append(rest)

result = [l[:-2] + c for l in lst if l[-1] == "" for c in replacements[l[-2]]]
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h']]
```

If the list can have more than one placeholder '', and if those can appear in the middle of the list, then things get a bit more complicated. You could make this a recursive function. (This could be made more efficient by using an index instead of repeatedly slicing the list.)

```
def replace(lst, last=None):
    if lst:
        first, *rest = lst
        if first == "":
            for repl in replacements[last]:
                yield from replace(repl + rest)
        else:
            for res in replace(rest, first):
                yield [first] + res
    else:
        yield []

for l in lst:
    for x in replace(l):
        print(x)
```

Output for `lst = [['a','b','c','','b',''],['c','b','','e','f'],['c','g','b',''],['b','x','y']]`:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'e', 'f', 'b', 'x', 'y']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'b', 'x', 'y']
['c', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'e', 'f']
['c', 'g', 'b', 'x', 'y']
['b', 'x', 'y']
```

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to merge 2 lists? If so, you can use  one of 2 ways :

Either use the `+` operator, or use the
`extend()` method.

And then you put it into a function.

Answer (score 0):

I made it with standard library only with comments. Please refer it.

```
mylist = [['a','b','c',''],['c','e','f'],['c','g','h']]

# I can't make sure whether the xlist's item is just one or not.
# So, I made it to find all
# And, you can see how to get the last value of a list as [-1]
xlist = [x for x in mylist if x[-1] == '']
ylist = [x for x in mylist if x[-1] != '']

result = []
# combine matrix of x x y
for x in xlist:
    for y in ylist:
        c = x + y # merge
        c = [i for i in c if i] # drop ''
        c = list(set(c)) # drop duplicates
        c.sort() # sort
        result.append(c)  # add to result

print (result)
```

The result is

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h']]
```

Answer (score 0):

try my solution 
 although it will change the order of list but it's quite simple code

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'c', ''], ['c', 'e', 'f'], ['c', 'g', 'h']]
lst[0].pop(-1)
print([list(set(lst[0]+lst[1])), list(set(lst[0]+lst[2]))])
```